# How to implement a filtered Set<Object> collection as a method in my mainprogramm

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to the coding business and got a maybe very trivial question for you folks.

So I have this java mainprogramm here:

```
package thalia.copy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

    // Get raw data strings from Daten class
    List<String> data = Daten.verkaufteBuecherDatenHolen();
    
    // Save split data strings into an array
    List<Book> books = bookArray( data );

    // Create a set of unique books of all type
    Set<Book> uniBooks = books.stream()
        .filter( book -> book.getClass().equals( Book.class ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toSet() );

    Set<Book> uniEBooks = books.stream()
        .filter( book -> book instanceof EBook ).map( book -> ( EBook ) book )
        .collect( Collectors.toSet() );

    Set<Book> uniAudio = books.stream()
        .filter( book -> book instanceof Audiobook )
        .map( book -> ( Audiobook ) book )
        .collect( Collectors.toSet() );

    // print unique books of all type to the console
    System.out.println( "List of unique paper books:" );
    uniBooks.forEach( System.out::println );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "List of unique EBooks:" );
    uniEBooks.forEach( System.out::println );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "List of unique EBooks:" );
    uniAudio.forEach( System.out::println );

    }

    // split data strings from "Daten" class method
    private static List<Book> bookArray( List<String> data ) {

    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    for ( String b : data ) {
        String split[] = b.split( ";" );

        if ( split[1].contentEquals( "Buch" ) ) {
        books.add( new Book
            ( split[0], split[1], Double.valueOf( split[2] ), 
                Integer.parseInt( split[3] ) ) );
        }

        if ( split[1].contentEquals( "Ebuch" ) ) {
        books.add( new EBook
            ( split[0], split[1], Double.valueOf( split[2] ), 
                Integer.parseInt( split[3] ), Integer.parseInt( split[4] ) ) );
        }

        if ( split[1].contentEquals( "Hoerbuch" ) ) {
        books.add( new Audiobook
            ( split[0], split[1], Double.valueOf( split[2] ), 
                Integer.parseInt( split[3] ), ( split[4] ) ) );
        }
    }

    return books;
    }
}
```

It's fairly simple, the code just filters out duplicates from a list of 50 strings with some data.
My main question concerns the "// Create a set of unique books of all type" part in line 19 of the code.
I would like to pack these lines into a separate method but I have absolutely no clue how to handle that. Can anyone show the the right syntax I need to use for that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unusual to put all subclasses of your `Book` types in one list. But you can theoretically copy the lines which you already have to extract a method or if you use an IDE like eclipse or intelij, go to the menu item "extract method" and let it be generated automatically.

```
private static Set<Book> getUniqueBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return books.stream()
           .filter(Book.class::isInstance)
           .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}

private static Set<EBook> getUniqueEBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return books.stream()
           .filter(EBook.class::isInstance)
           .map(EBook.class::cast)
           .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}

private static Set<Audiobook> getUniqueAudioBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return books.stream()
           .filter(Audiobook.class::isInstance)
           .map(Audiobook.class::cast)
           .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}
```

Note i have used method references for the casting, which i think are more readable.

But as @AmirAfghani already mentioned in his answer the first method is pointless because as the input is a list of books, instead of using streams you could just do (assuming the class impliments `hashCode` and `equals`)

```
private static Set<Book> getUniqueBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return new HashSet<>(books);
}
```

You can use above ethods as follows in your main:

```
List<Book> books = bookArray( data );
...
Set<Audiobook> uniAudio = getUniqueAudioBooks(books);
Set<EBook> uniEBooks = getUniqueEBooks(books);
```

But if you don't want your result sets to contain your subclasses but the superclass as type, then you can combine all the above methods into one which groups your list (e.g. by class name) and returns a map of type `Map<String,Set<Book>>` :

```
private static Map<String,Set<Book>> getGroupedBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return books.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            e -> e.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

and use this method like:

```
Set<Book> uniAudio = getGroupedBooks(books).get("Audiobook");
Set<Book> uniEBooks = getGroupedBooks(books).get("EBook");
```

**EDIT**

It may seem complicated now, but once you get used to streams and maps it is actually quite simple. The method groups your books by their names and produces a structure with keys and value pairs. The keys here are the class names and the values are a set of book objects that belong to this class.

By iterating over your list and getting the class name over `e.getClass().getSimpleName()` for each object in the list you can group them by their class names. All objects of class `EBook` move in the group with key `"EBook"` and all objects `Book` move in the group `"Book"` and so on

The resulting map looks something like

```
Map<String,Set<Book>> map = 
      { "Book"      : [Book1, Book2, BooK3, ...],
        "AudioBook" : [AudioBook1, AudioBook2, AudioBook3, ...],
        "EBook"     : [EBook1, EBook2, EBook3,...]}
```

And by calling `map.get(key)` you will get the `value` from the map which is associated with the `key`.

```
getGroupedBooks(books) // calls the method which returns the map 
     .get("Audiobook"); // get the value (the set) which is associated with the key "Audiobook"
```

Maybe here is another clear and simple example: Suppose you have a list of animals

```
List<Animal> animalsList = List.of(new Cat("Katzi"), 
                                       new Dog("Bello"),
                                       new Cat("Miau"),
                                       new Donkey("Don"),
                                       new Dog("Wuff"));
```

and you want to group them by species and create a map from the list, you can use above logic to generate something like:

```
      { "Cat"    : [Katzi, Miau],
        "Dog"    : [Bello, Wuff],
        "Donkey" : [Don]}
```

To your first question regarding `return new HashSet<>(books);`, a set as opposed to a list by definition does not allow duplicates. For example, a list could look like this:

```
List<String> myList = List.of("one", "one", "two", "three", "two", "three", "one");
```

To create a set from this list (a container without duplicates) you can certainly iterate over the list or use streams and call `Collectors.toSet` something like:

```
private static Set<String> getUniqueStrings(List<String> myList) {
   return myList.stream()
                .distinct()
                .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}
```

But there is a much easier way to get the same result with the constructor of  a set to which you just pass the list and it will do the filtering of duplicate elements for you, i.e you dont need to iterate over the list

```
private static Set<String> getUniqueStrings(List<String> myList) {
   return new HashSet<>(myList);
}
```

Both methods produce the exact same result, return the uniuqe elements of the list.

```
[one, two, three]
```

But the second is shorter, simpler, clearer and perhaps more easily readable

Comment: Thanks your first suggestion is kinda what I am looking for. Regarding the second suggestion with: "private static Set<Book> getUniqueBooks(List<Book> books) {
return new HashSet<>(books); }". I kinda struggle to comprehend what you are trying to tell me with that suggestion. I know that the suggested "getUniqueBooks" method gives out a list of all unique books, but that's it. As I mentioned I'm really new to java programming and this is the first time that I'm working with Lists and Sets, not to mention maps, which sounds like vodoo to me.

Comment: Ok I implemented the "private static Map<String,Set<Book>> getGroupedBooks(List<Book> books)" method as suggested and it works. But It still baffles me. This is like black magic for me. Could you explain to me what the method actually does? At the moment I'm feeling like getting a rocket into the air with absolutely no clue on how to land that thing in one piece again...

Comment: @T4ke Please see my edit. Hope it is some how clear now.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks a lot for your time. I was really confused by the fact that I could enter something like "Book" into .get("Book"), which for me was a notation for a String, until now. Thanks again for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you just wanted to wrap that code in a method you could just create one :

```
private static Set<String> calculateUniqueBooks(List<Book> books) {
   return books.stream()
               .filter( book -> book.getClass().equals( Book.class ) )
               .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}
```

But I think what you're doing in this method is kind of pointless and doesn't really do anything to the Book list.  Just by virtue of declaring `List<Book>` you're guaranteed that only book's will be in that list.

**For example :** If your Book class had only two attributes (let's say 'name' and 'author') and you had two books with the same name and same author, that code you wrote will not reduce those down to one entry.

What you should be doing is implementing `hashCode` and `equals` on the `Book` class and all of it's sub-classes, and just create a set where you pass your List into it :

```
Set<Book> uniqueBooks = new HashSet<>(books)
```

This will trigger the code you write in `hashCode` and `equals` to determine uniqueness in the `Set`

Comment: Oh yep, thanks for pointing that out. I do have a Book.class that has a hashCode and equals method. Book.class also extends to the EBook and Audiobook classes. Those methods filter out the duplicates from my list. Should have mentioned that in the explanation.

Your example does help me out though. How should the calculateUniqueBooks method body look like if I want to inculde uniBooks, uniEBooks and uniAudio in there?

Comment: I don't think you actually read my post through.  What do you think that method is doing with the filter?  It's not doing anything, it's pointless.

Comment: Well currently line 19 to 42 prints out a list of unique books, EBooks and Audiobooks to console. I want to pack that stuff in a method that I can call up to do the same in my mainprogramm.